# Powershell Forms refresh GUI

Tags: powershell

The script is a simple administration tool to indicate the status of three windows services and to toggle them.

Everything works fine but I don't get it done to implement the refreshment of the GUI.

I want to show up the related status in labels and to hide the non-clickable buttons. I was playing around so far with a timer, but the GUI still doesn't refresh..

```
#variables
$ums = get-service "UMS Server"
$mySQL = get-service "mySQL56"
$maria = get-service "MariaDB_10.1.21"

function OnApplicationLoad {
return $true 
}
function OnApplicationExit {
$script:ExitCode = 0 
}



function generateForm {
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


$UMSDatabaseadministration = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$UMSDatabaseadministration.Text = "UMS Database administration"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.TopMost = $true
$UMSDatabaseadministration.Width = 614
$UMSDatabaseadministration.Height = 316
$UMSDatabaseadministration.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer #$UMSDatabaseadministration
$timer.Interval = 1000  # once per second
$timer.Add_Tick({ $UMSDatabaseadministration.Refresh() })


#button 1 start UMS
$button11 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button11.Text = "start"
$button11.Width = 60
$button11.Height = 30

if ($ums.Status -eq "Running"){
$button11.visible = $false
}
$button11.Add_Click({
                        $ums.start()


                        })
$button11.location = new-object system.drawing.point(303,38)
$button11.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($button11)

#button 2 stop UMS
$button15 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button15.Text = "stop"
$button15.Width = 60
$button15.Height = 30

if ($ums.Status -eq "Stopped"){
$button15.visible = $false
}
$button15.Add_Click({$ums.stop()})
$button15.location = new-object system.drawing.point(409,39)
$button15.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($button15)

#button 3 start mySQL
$button12 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button12.Text = "start"
$button12.Width = 60
$button12.Height = 30

if ($maria.Status -eq "Running" -Or $mySQL.Status -eq "Running"){
$button12.visible = $false
}
$button12.Add_Click({$mySQL.start()})
$button12.location = new-object system.drawing.point(303,98)
$button12.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($button12)

#button 4 stop mySQL
$button14 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button14.Text = "stop"
$button14.Width = 60
$button14.Height = 30

if ($mySQL.Status -eq "Stopped"){
$button14.visible = $false
}
$button14.Add_Click({$mySQL.stop()})
$button14.location = new-object system.drawing.point(410,99)
$button14.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($button14)

#button 5 start mariaDB
$button13 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button13.Text = "start"
$button13.Width = 60
$button13.Height = 30

if ($mySQL.Status -eq "Running" -Or $maria.Status -eq "Running"){
$button13.visible = $false
}
$button13.Add_Click({$maria.start()})
$button13.location = new-object system.drawing.point(302,147)
$button13.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($button13)



#button 6 stop mariaDB
$button16 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button16.Text = "stop"
$button16.Width = 60
$button16.Height = 30

if ($maria.Status -eq "Stopped"){
$button16.visible = $false
}
$button16.Add_Click({$maria.stop()})
$button16.location = new-object system.drawing.point(410,148)
$button16.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($button16)


$button17 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button17.Text = "shut down UMS Server and toggle DB`'s"

$button17.Add_Click({ 

#variables
$ums = get-service "UMS Server"
$mySQL = get-service "mySQL56"
$maria = get-service "MariaDB_10.1.21"

if ($ums.Status -eq "Running") {$ums.stop()}

if ($mySQL.Status -eq "Running") {$mySQL.stop(); $maria.start()}

if ($maria.Status -eq "Running") {$maria.stop(); $mySQL.start()}

})


$button17.Width = 166
$button17.Height = 42
$button17.location = new-object system.drawing.point(303,209)
$button17.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($button17)



$label18 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label18.Text = "UMS Server is:"
$label18.AutoSize = $true
$label18.Width = 25
$label18.Height = 10
$label18.location = new-object system.drawing.point(33,38)
$label18.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label18)


$label19 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label19.Text = "mySQL is:"
$label19.AutoSize = $true
$label19.Width = 25
$label19.Height = 10
$label19.location = new-object system.drawing.point(33,95)
$label19.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label19)


$label20 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label20.Text = "mariaDB is:"
$label20.AutoSize = $true
$label20.Width = 25
$label20.Height = 10
$label20.location = new-object system.drawing.point(34,146)
$label20.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label20)

#status UMS red
$label24 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label24.Text = $ums.status
$label24.AutoSize = $true
$label24.ForeColor = "#fe0004"
$label24.Width = 25
$label24.Height = 10

if ($ums.status -eq "Running"){
$label24.visible = $false
}
$label24.location = new-object system.drawing.point(152,37)
$label24.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label24)

#status UMS green
$label25 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label25.Text = $ums.status
$label25.AutoSize = $true
$label25.ForeColor = "#149600"
$label25.Width = 25
$label25.Height = 10

if ($ums.status -eq "Stopped"){
$label25.visible = $false
}
$label25.location = new-object system.drawing.point(153,40)
$label25.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label25)

#status mySQL red
$label26 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label26.Text = $mySQL.status
$label26.AutoSize = $true
$label26.ForeColor = "#ff0004"
$label26.Width = 25
$label26.Height = 10

if ($mySQL.status -eq "Running"){
$label26.visible = $false
}
$label26.location = new-object system.drawing.point(152,94)
$label26.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label26)

#status mySQL green
$label27 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label27.Text = $mySQL.status
$label27.AutoSize = $true
$label27.ForeColor = "#149600"
$label27.Width = 25
$label27.Height = 10

if ($mySQL.status -eq "Stopped"){
$label27.visible = $false
}
$label27.location = new-object system.drawing.point(152,96)
$label27.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label27)

#status mariaDB red
$label28 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label28.Text = $maria.status
$label28.AutoSize = $true
$label28.ForeColor = "#ff0004"
$label28.Width = 25
$label28.Height = 10

if ($maria.status -eq "Running"){
$label28.visible = $false
}
$label28.location = new-object system.drawing.point(151,145)
$label28.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label28)

#status mariaDB green
$label29 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$label29.Text = $maria.status
$label29.AutoSize = $true
$label29.ForeColor = "#149600"
$label29.Width = 25
$label29.Height = 10

if ($maria.status -eq "Stopped"){
$label29.visible = $false
}
$label29.location = new-object system.drawing.point(151,145)
$label29.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$UMSDatabaseadministration.controls.Add($label29)


[void]
$UMSDatabaseadministration.ShowDialog()
$UMSDatabaseadministration.Dispose()


}



if(OnApplicationLoad -eq $true)
{
GenerateForm | Out-Null
$timer.Start()
OnApplicationExit
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to the minimum code required to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I must say that your code needs a lot of TLC. You shouldn't label your buttons or labels 1-20. Makes the code look messy and 15 days down the line you will have no idea what the code says. At lines 2-4 and 128-130 you define your variables twice.

What I have done now is create this Service GUI that will not just help you out, but anyone looking to do the same kind of task. You simple add the services you want into the Param function.

## First we see if you are an Administrator, because not everyone is.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
function Test-Admin {
  $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
  $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}
if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) 
    {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } 
    else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
}

exit
}
```

**We create a central location to have the parameters.**

Note that you see that I use the `$Global:` You can read about that here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes

```
Function Param{
$Global:Option1 = get-service "Hamachi2Svc"
$Global:Option2 = get-service "NitroUpdateService"
$Global:Option3 = get-service "TeamViewer"

$Global:Option1Txt=$Global:Option1.Displayname
$Global:Option2Txt=$Global:Option2.Displayname
$Global:Option3Txt=$Global:Option3.Displayname
}
```

**Now we create the Form**

```
Function ServiceAdminForm {
    $Form.Close()
    $Form.Dispose()
    Test-Admin
    MakeForm
}
```

**Now we define the functions that our buttons will use.**

```
Function Option1 {
if ($Global:Option1.Status -eq "Running"){ Stop-Service $Global:Option1
}
else {Start-Service $Global:Option1}
}

Function Option2 {
if ($Global:Option2.Status -eq "Running"){ Stop-Service $Global:Option2
}
else {Start-Service $Global:Option2}
}

Function Option3 {
if ($Global:Option3.Status -eq "Running"){ Stop-Service $Global:Option3
}
else {Start-Service $Global:Option3}
}

Function Toggle {
if ($Global:Option1.Status -eq "Running") {$Global:Option1.stop()}
if ($Global:Option2.Status -eq "Running") {$Global:Option2.stop(); $Global:Option3.start()}
if ($Global:Option3.Status -eq "Running") {$Global:Option3.stop(); $Global:Option2.start()}
}
```

**Now we make the layout of the GUI**

Calling the parameters and the button functions.

```
Function MakeForm {
Param

    $script:Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = "Service Administration"
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $Form.Font = $Font

    #Label for Option1
    $Global:Option1lbl = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $Global:Option1lbl.Text = $Global:Option1.Status
    $Global:Option1lbl.AutoSize = $true
    $Global:Option1lbl.Width = 25
    $Global:Option1lbl.Height = 10
    $Global:Option1lbl.location = new-object system.drawing.point(5,90)

    #Label for Option2
    $Global:Option2lbl = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $Global:Option2lbl.Text = $Global:Option2.Status
    $Global:Option2lbl.AutoSize = $true
    $Global:Option2lbl.Width = 25
    $Global:Option2lbl.Height = 10
    $Global:Option2lbl.location = new-object system.drawing.point(5,150)

    #Label for Option3
    $Global:Option3lbl = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $Global:Option3lbl.Text = $Global:Option3.Status
    $Global:Option3lbl.AutoSize = $true
    $Global:Option3lbl.Width = 25
    $Global:Option3lbl.Height = 10
    $Global:Option3lbl.location = new-object system.drawing.point(5,210)

    #Refresh/Reload
    $Reloadbtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Reloadbtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,10)
    $Reloadbtn.AutoSize = $true
    $Reloadbtn.Text = "Reload"
    $Reloadbtn.Add_Click({ServiceAdminForm})
    
    #Toggle
    $Togglebtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Togglebtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,10)
    $Togglebtn.AutoSize = $true
    $Togglebtn.Text = "Toggle"
    $Togglebtn.Add_Click({Toggle})

    #Button Option1
    $Global:Option1btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Global:Option1btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,60)
    $Global:Option1btn.AutoSize = $true
    $Global:Option1btn.Text = "$Global:Option1Txt"
    $Global:Option1btn.Add_Click({Option1})

    #Button Option2
    $Global:Option2btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Global:Option2btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,120)
    $Global:Option2btn.AutoSize = $true
    $Global:Option2btn.Text = "$Global:Option2Txt"
    $Global:Option2btn.Add_Click({Option2})

    #Button Option3
    $Global:Option3btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Global:Option3btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,180)
    $Global:Option3btn.AutoSize = $true
    $Global:Option3btn.Text = "$Global:Option3Txt"
    $Global:Option3btn.Add_Click({Option3})

    #Form Controls
    $Form.Controls.Add($Global:Option1lbl)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Global:Option2lbl)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Global:Option3lbl)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Reloadbtn)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Togglebtn)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Global:Option1btn)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Global:Option2btn)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Global:Option3btn)
    $Form.ShowDialog()
}
MakeForm
```

Maybe someone has a better way to refresh, but reloading the form does the job.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! In the mean time I did clean out the code and I came up with the same idea, to reload the form for refreshing. It pretty much does the job.

Comment: Completly recreating the form for just a form refresh? Did you try $Form.Refresh()?